# Magento 2.4 Parse Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, backend

Need some assistance with this one.

Within Magento my store seems to be throwing up a parse error whenever you try to do any simple tasks like sending order notes to customers from within Magento.

ERR MSG:
"ParseError:syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_STRING), expected :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Here's some images to show the error.

https://postimg.cc/gallery/cLJTxSb

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You had this error because you using PHP version under 7.4, please upgrade your PHP version that corresponds to your Magento version. You can find which PHP you should use here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html